# pandas DataFrame.plot() method

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to data science and trying some python libraries. I know it sound a bit silly but I'm confused with the code below, which i found on the pandas docs. I'm assuming that 'ts' is a pd obj, but how exactly a pd object can use matplotlib method here? What's the connection between pandas and matplotlib? Can someone explain that to me, thank you.

```
In [3]: ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))


In [4]: ts = ts.cumsum()

In [5]: ts.plot()

Out[5]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fa17967caf0>`
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in? This should output a line graph of the cumulative results of the random series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib is a library that makes it easy to generate plots in Python. Pandas is a library that helps you perform vector and matrix operations in Python.

According to the Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html):

> The plot method on Series and DataFrame is just a simple wrapper around plt.plot()

So the only connection between Pandas and Matplotlib is that Pandas uses Matplotlib to generate the plot for you.

If you want to *see* that plot, you have to add a couple of extra lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```